# How to use Variables generated in one function in another function

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I pass multiple variables generated in one function to another funtion? Like for example

```
fun1(){
var1=$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc1.txt)
var2=$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc2.txt)
var3=$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc3.txt)
}

fun2(){
echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
}
```

I am new to bash still learning. Couldn't get how to solve this :(

Comment: BTW, in bash you can use this syntax to read a file's contents into a variable:  `var1=$(< /home/ubuntu/abc1.txt)` .

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be enough to call fun1, variables defined in it
will be available in fun2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

fun1(){
    var1="$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc1.txt)"
    var2="$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc2.txt)"
    var3="$(cat /home/ubuntu/abc3.txt)"
}

fun2(){
    echo "$var1"
    echo "$var2"
    echo "$var3"
}

fun1
fun2
```

Remember it's a good practice to double quotes variable in most cases
to prevent [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/wordsplitting)
and to add [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/shebang_(unix)).

Comment: This didn't worked :(

Comment: You have to be more specific. What didn't it work? What happened and what did you expect to happen?